# Multicore processing of independent jobs

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am interested in applying the Python multiprocessing module (or any suitable equivalent) to speed up independent processing of multiple data files. Currently the processing code is CPU limited on a single core ie 100% cpu until it completes.

I have a number of data files each of which require some simple, but relatively CPU intense, processing operations. The processing operations have been cast into a single function which takes the file to be processed and a few other arguments. Since each processing operation is entirely independent, multicore processing would seem to be a perfect solution.

I've seen various examples using the Process and Queue methods in the multiprocessing module, but if I'm honest I can't really see how to apply them to my problem.

In essence, I want to use all 8 cores in my machine to chew through the processing operation using a job queuing system. At the start, 8 files are processed at the same time, 1 file processing on each core. When a one of the cores has completed its processing operations, I want it to process the next file in the queue. This loop is continued until all files have been processed. Since the processing operations are independent there doesn't need to be any cross-thread communication.

Does any one have a simple example of how to do this in Python?

Thanks

Comment: This could be a good read for you: https://www.praetorian.com/blog/multi-core-and-distributed-programming-in-python

Comment: https://mikecvet.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/parallel-mapreduce-in-python/ may give you some good leads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to an external runner and the associated overhead thereof, one possible option is to use a task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). It contains all the required machinery out of the box. You just have to wrap your individual work units in the `@task` decorator and enqueue them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping to use "standard" Python where possible. ie minimise external packages such as runners